# Getting error in ajax request when calling API

Tags: ajax

Can anyone tell me that what is the error in my code? When I call my API, it could not able to get success.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $.ajax({
        url:"https://www.erp.tpci.in/api/badge/list?authId=indusfood&authPassword=indusfood@123&page=1&company_name=&name=&code=&badge_id=141&buyer_id=1300&limit=10",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
          console.log(data);
        },

        error: function(error) {
            console.log('Error');
        }

      });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Please add the content type eg: contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"

Comment: I have added but result still same.

Comment: I think its blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource